# github error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database

Tags: git, github, chown

When I run these commands from my App folder:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit details"
git push
```

I get the error:

```
mycompaq@ubuntu:~/myapp$ git add .
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects

error: app/views/reviews/update.js.erb: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file app/views/reviews/update.js.erb
fatal: updating files failed
mycompaq@ubuntu:~/myapp$
```

I tried this command:

```
chown -R user:user /project/directory
```

But seeing as I got in a *whole load of trouble* in the first place by running commands I wasn't sure about, I want to know if this is the correct solution.

What should the exact syntax be, if the user is 'Christophe', and the folder where my Rails app is stored is called 'myapp'. I mean should it be

```
chown -R user:christophe /myapp/app/views/reviews/update.js.erb
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
chown [ -f ] [ -h ] [ -R ] Owner [ :Group ] { File ... | Directory ... }
```

From the [man page](http://nersp.nerdc.ufl.edu/~dicke3/nerspcs/chown.html)

> The chown command changes the owner of the file specified by the File
>   parameter to the user specified by the Owner parameter. The value
>   of the Owner parameter can be a user ID or a login name found in the
>   /etc/passwd file. Optionally, a group can also be specified. The value
>   of the Group parameter can be a group ID or a group name found in
>   the /etc/group file.

About the -R option

> -R 
>   Descends directories recursively, changing the ownership for each
>   file. When a symbolic link is encountered and the link points to a
>   directory, the ownership of that directory is changed but the directory
>   is not further transversed.

So

```
chown -R user:christophe /myapp/app/views/reviews/update.js.erb
```

Would change the owner of the `update.js.erb` file to the user `user` in the group `christophe`, which is probably not what you want.

In your case changing the owner of the repo to yourself, i.e.

```
sudo chown -R christophe /path/to/your/local/repo
```

should suffice.

If you don't know your user name, you can find it out with the `whoami` command.

Comment: I tried 'chown -R christophe /myapp', and also 'Christophe1' (my github user name) but I keep getting 'chown: invalid user: `Christophe1' Probably a dumb question, but how can I find out what 'user' should be ? It is my machine, afterall, and my name is Christophe!

Comment: Cool, nice one. I'll take a note of that. But when I run 'chown -R christophecompaq myapp' I get a load of 'Operation not permitted' messages. And then git add . gives me the original error.Thanks for ur description of chown and 'R though.

Comment: `sudo chown -R christophecompaq myapp`

Comment: Hey, nice! I edited your answer to include some of these comments, if you don;t mind - to make it easier for others.

Comment: I integrated your suggestion, glad you have solved in any case.

Answer (score 59):

You accidentally committed a file or folder to git using elevated permissions and now git can't modify those objects.   It is safe to recursively force ownership of all files under `.git/objects/` to your current user to clear the problem.

1. Make sure you're inside the repository where you're getting the error.
2. Get your username by typing

   `whoami`
3. Enter this command

   `sudo chown -R your_user_name .git/*`
4. Finally

   `git add .`

Answer (score 0):

You can give access to all the files in .git/ folder. Just run the following command:

```
sudo chmod a+xrw .git/*
```